# On change of checkbox state remain same in UI

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.is_permitted" (change)="changeStatus()">

changeStatus() {
rowData.is_permitted = true;
}
```

If I uncheck checkbox but conditionally I want to select the checkbox, the flag updated but not affect in UI.

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: Its working as expected. Check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vmnl2

Comment: It doesn't (when you click on `Change` label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nph2u1). After unchecking the checkbox, the value is set to `true` in code but the checkbox remains unchecked.

---

You can do the following to override the action of the user with a change in code:

- Force an immediate change detection by calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`
- Set the value to `true`
- Let the change detection mecanism update the checkbox to reflect the updated value

In the code below, I handle the `ngModelChange` event. The conditional behavior mentioned in the question is simulated with the `keepChecked` property:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  [(ngModel)]="rowData.is_permitted" 
  (ngModelChange)="changeStatus()">
```

```
changeStatus() {
  if (this.keepChecked) {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.rowData.is_permitted = true;
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpsr1q) for a demo.

---

A similar result could be obtained by setting the value asynchronously in a `setTimeout` callback:

```
changeStatus() {
  if (this.keepChecked) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.rowData.is_permitted = true;
    });
  }
}
```

but I prefer to keep the code synchronous by calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,
After changing the input, it remains true.

So, when `rowData.is_permitted` is true, you need to make it false.

`rowData.is_permitted` is false, you need to make it true.

If this is your problem, try do it by changing `changeStatus` function:

```
rowData.is_permitted = !rowData.is_permitted;
```

rowData.is_permitted will get the opposite value.

Working example that I forked from @SunilSingh is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtup8z?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change ngModel value on click. May be `rowData.is_permitted` default value is `true` so, on click it is not changed by your function.
Your changeStatus function will be

```
changeStatus() {
    rowData.is_permitted = !rowData.is_permitted;
}
```