# Angular change false to true on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I've got a service that has an array of selected ID's. When I init a component I perform a check for presence of that component's ID in the array. However, Angular throws an exception that value has been changed after view check.

I've tried to add `detectChanges()` right after `this._checked = true`, tried `markForCheck()`. Also, I've tried to move both cases to different life cycle hooks with no success except for that it started working although throwing an error.

Comment: `detectChanges()` will only work for the called component and its children, please show your full code. Try with `setTimeout(() => {this._checked = true})`. This will probably work..

Comment: try changing it to the afterViewInit hook?

Comment: Call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` before changing the value.

Comment: @ConnorsFan No, it goes after.

Comment: @xyz forgot to mention. I've tried that as well as Promise.then

Comment: @ConnorsFan, detectChanges is synchronous and checks views downwards, markForCheck is asynchronous and marks views to be checked upwards. You can do markForCheck before (which makes no difference), but detectChanges always goes after.

Comment: @pokrishka - `detectChanges` sometimes needs to be called before but it is when the view is not updated properly in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351917/1009922). My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular change detection is like meat grinder and you are trying to alter the meat in the process. Typically, `markForCheck()` should be enough in this case. If you post your full code we can try to figure out why it's not working in your situation. If all fails, you can always do:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.youChanges();
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
});
```

Comment: It turned out that I've got also another error with the same text, so that works